# ListBox for Windows Phone development

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Can I make a listbox only show one option at a time and have a possibility of scrolling down for more?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [the Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)

The [ListPicker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/WP7ListPicker.aspx) might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

ListPicker might be what you need, but there should also be nothing to stop you from having the ListBox be the size of a single option. Well - except for usability perhaps, but with ListPicker being part of a separate, big library and having issues of its own - it might be what you need.

One problem with ListPicker is - it navigates to a separate page if it needs to display a lot of items, which might work great in some situations, but adds some additional complexity.